# Is it possible to broadcast psbt in bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip174-psbt

Is it possible to broadcast psbt in bitcoin core without converting to raw transaction?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible without using `finalizepsbt` first to get the raw transaction. This is intentional as PSBTs will primarily be incomplete and thus cannot be broadcast.